# How to implement reactive form approach to editable primeng data tables

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng

Here I am adding some editable prime data table, But I am unable to validate the fields using rective forms.

```
    <p-dataTable [value]="fspChargeCodeList" selectionMode="single" [loading]="loading">

  <p-column styleClass="col-button">

      <ng-template let-fspChargeCode="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <span  *ngIf="!fspChargeCode.isEditable">
          <a class="attachments-mwa" (click)="editRow(fspChargeCode)">
          <i class="fas fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
        </a>
       </span>
       <span *ngIf="fspChargeCode.isEditable">
          <a class="attachments-mwa" (click)="editChargeCode(fspChargeCode)">
          <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
          </a>
       </span>
        <a class="delete-mwa" (click)="delete(fspChargeCode)">
          <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
        </a>

      </ng-template>

    </p-column>

   <p-column styleClass="text-md-center text-center" field=chargeCode header="{{columns['chargeCode']}}">
      <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <div *ngIf="!row.isEditable">{{row.chargeCode}}</div>
        <div *ngIf="row.isEditable">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="row.chargeCode" formControlName="'chargeCode'">
        </div>
     </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
ts

editRow(fspChargeCode: any) {
   this.fspChargeCodeList.filter(fspChargeCode => fspChargeCode.isEditable)
            .map(r => { r.isEditable = false; return r })
        fspChargeCode.isEditable = true;
}

   validateChargeCodeForm() {
        var chargecodepatterns = "^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{5}$";
        this.chargeCodeAddForm = this.fb.group({
            chargeCode: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(11),
            Validators.maxLength(11), Validators.pattern(chargecodepatterns)]],
             })
             }
```

Can any one have approach please post or comment the answer

Thanks in advance

G.Soumya

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a little bit different syntax that [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/validation) shows. Have a look on `password` in the example. There is `Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]))`, so maybe you should have `Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(11), Validators.maxLength(11), Validators.pattern(chargecodepatterns)]])` too.

Also, you're using Table which is deprecated. We should use [TurboTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) now (so you need to update PrimeNG in project). Maybe validation itself is fine and it's just table's issue. (And I think that @foxgang meant that)

Answer (score -1):

Data table not  maintained anymore. Can u try with turbo table ?

Comment: I did not understood your answer, can you elabarate please

Comment: you can look here https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=56402